# ubuntu will not install on my lenovo n580

Tags: lenovo

I have a Lenovo n580 and I've been trying to install Ubuntu on it and all I get is a white screen after I boot through live cd and usb. I tried going to the bios to change to legacy but it does not help. Any suggestions?